# ¿Cómo posicionar mis cartas una al lado de la otra?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Las cartas están una debajo de la otra pero soy muy nuevo en esto y no he podido acomodar bien mi pagina web,necesito ayuda , asesoría y mejoras. Muchas gracias. [image]

```css
/* CSS files add styling rules to your content */

body {
  
  margin: 0em;
}

.cover {
  height:400px;
  background-image:url(https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_carl-raw-m3hn2kn5bns-unsplash.jpg?v=1649377803016);
    color:white;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}

.card{
  border:0 !important;
  box-shadow:3px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  background:pink;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Mi Primera Pagina Web</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!AQUI VA EL LINK DIRECTO DE CSS>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>

        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ubicacion</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Acerca de</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div
        class="cover d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
      >
        <h1>LaCuevaDePipe</h1>
        <p>Comparte El Conocimiento</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Conoce Más</button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_masahiro-miyagi-goayhhgah8c-unsplash.jpg?v=1649379913884"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="Barrio Chino"
            />

            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">VerPeliculas</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Aqui podras encontrar la mejor pagina para ver peliculas online.
              </p>
              <a href="https://pelispop.me/" class="btn btn-warning"
                >Dale Click</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_marcela-laskoski-yrtflrlo2dq-unsplash.jpg?v=1649383727617"
                class="card-img-top"
                alt="musica dj"
              />

              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">MiPlayList</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Aqui Esta Mi PlayList De Musica Preferida.
                </p>
                <a
                  href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3Fz-TDfJ8xTtktQd95qo0H80WcNLahiL"
                  class="btn btn-danger"
                  >Dale Play</a
                >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_luca-bravo-xjxwbfso2f0-unsplash.jpg?v=1649383876921"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="programacion"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">CursoParaCrearPaginasWeb</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Aqui encontraras el curso que me enseño mis primeros pasos
                    para crear una pagina web.
                  </p>
                  <a
                    href="https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/primera-pagina-2019"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                    >Comienza YA</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo le hacemos? ¿Adivinamos tu código?

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/proximal-aquamarine-soccer

Aqui esta el link para modificar el codigo , disculpa la ignoracia , apenas entro al mundo de stack , Espero con ansias tu ayuda <3

Comment: Por favor, elimina tu respuesta, el código se coloca en la pregunta la cual puedes editar cuantas veces quieras. Lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y realiza el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el sitio. Ya coloqué el código en tu pregunta. Si quieres responderle a alguien, utiliza los comentarios, no las respuestas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Establece el contenedor donde tienes las tarjetas con la clase `row` y luego con las clases `col-md-X`,  `col-sm-X` y `col-lg-X` juega con las columnas como más te gusten. He agregado a `d-sm-flex align-self-sm-stretch` para forzar a todas las columnas ser del mismo tamaño.

```css
/* CSS files add styling rules to your content */

body { 
    margin: 0em;
  }
  
  .cover {
    height:400px;
    background-image:url(https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_carl-raw-m3hn2kn5bns-unsplash.jpg?v=1649377803016);
      color:white;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-blend-mode:darken;
  }

  .card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Mi Primera Pagina Web</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!AQUI VA EL LINK DIRECTO DE CSS>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ubicacion</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Acerca de</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="cover d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
            <h1>LaCuevaDePipe</h1>
            <p>Comparte El Conocimiento</p>
            <button class="btn btn-success">Conoce Más</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-sm-flex align-self-sm-stretch col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card m-2">
                    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_masahiro-miyagi-goayhhgah8c-unsplash.jpg?v=1649379913884"
                        class="card-img-top object-fit" alt="Barrio Chino" />

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">VerPeliculas</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Aqui podras encontrar la mejor pagina para ver peliculas online.
                        </p>
                        <a href="https://pelispop.me/" class="btn btn-warning">Dale Click</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="d-sm-flex align-self-sm-stretch col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card m-2" >
                    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_marcela-laskoski-yrtflrlo2dq-unsplash.jpg?v=1649383727617"
                        class="card-img-top" alt="musica dj" />

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">MiPlayList</h5>
                        <p class="card-text ">
                            Aqui Esta Mi PlayList De Musica Preferida.
                        </p>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3Fz-TDfJ8xTtktQd95qo0H80WcNLahiL"
                            class="btn btn-danger">Dale Play</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="d-sm-flex align-self-sm-stretch col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
                <div class="card m-2" >
                    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/199f6c62-0f89-4348-b3f4-0aa18564ef29/rsz_luca-bravo-xjxwbfso2f0-unsplash.jpg?v=1649383876921"
                        class="card-img-top" alt="programacion" />
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">CursoParaCrearPaginasWeb</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            Aqui encontraras el curso que me enseño mis primeros pasos
                            para crear una pagina web.
                        </p>
                        <a href="https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/primera-pagina-2019" class="btn btn-success">Comienza
                            YA</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si pones todas las cartas dentro de un mismo div y le das las clases `row d-flex justify-content-around` o `row d-flex justify-content-between` los elementos hijos se repartirán automáticamente en el espacio disponible.